# Navigation: Is it okay to have the same dropdown multiple times?

Tags: website-design, interaction-design, navigation, interface

So my navigation is:

```
CARDS | DECKS | DECKBUILDER | ...
```

Each of them have basically the same dropdown items. You either want to see Cards, Decks or the Deckbuilder for one specific champion (Barik, Buck, etc ..).

Now I've styled this fancy dropdown menu as seen below. The question is: Would it be a bad idea to reuse it for all three menus? The images would be the same, the titles on the items would be slightly different ("BARIK CARDS", "BARIK DECKS", "NEW BARIK DECK").

I'm not sure if it would confuse the user. It would be kinda hard to distinguish between different menus, wouldn't it be?

But the alternative, having 3 different dropdown menus sounds even worse.
The second alternative: not using any dropdowns but a interim stage (*click* CARDS, new page, choose/*click* champion, new page)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this
[image]

using cards/decks/deckbuilder as horizontal tabs and the cards in a vertical menu on the left